# Can my web host prevent me from connecting to an external database?

Tags: postgresql, cpanel

I have two servers:
CP server - A website is hosted on a server running cpanel (I only have access to cpanel)
VPS server - A server running ubuntu and postgresql

I am pretty sure I did everything correct when I enabled remote access to the postgres database on the VPS server (I connected successfully from two other machines, on two different IPs). However, when I am running exactly the same PHP-code on the CP server, it fails to connect. I tried using fsockopen on this server. It does not work when I try to connect to the VPS server on port 5432, but works on port 80. On the other machines I tried on, it works on port 5432.

So, is it possible that my web hosting provider (the CP server) is blocking this connection somehow?

Comment: If your database access uses a particular, special port, then it is *possible* that your server blocks processes running on it from attempting to access that port.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You should check with your ISP.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web hosting configuration, and can only be answered by the OP's ISP

Comment: The question was if it was possible, not if they are doing it!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webhosting provider is having firewall installed and its blocking the outgoing connection to the postgresql server.